# When taking the exponential of a diagonalizable matrix, why can the eigenvector matrices be taken out of the exponential?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given diagonalizable matrix $A$ with diagonal form $D$, $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $P$ is the matrix of eigenvectors, why is it that that $e^A=e^{PDP^{-1}}=Pe^DP^{-1}$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$e^{A}=I+A+A^2/2+ \ldots$

$A^{n}=(PDP^{-1})^{n}=PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}\cdots PDP^{-1}=PD^{n}P^{-1}$

Thus

$e^{A}=PP^{-1}+PDP^{-1}+PD^{2}P^{-1}/2+\ldots$.

Factoring out the $P$ and $P^{-1}$ on the left and right gives

$e^{A}=P(I+D+D^{2}/2+\ldots)P^{-1}=Pe^{D}P^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$e^{PDP^{-1}}=I+PDP^{-1}+\frac{1}{2}PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}+\frac{1}{6}PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}+\cdots$$
$$=PIP^{-1}+PDP^{-1}+P\frac{1}{2}D^2P^{-1}+P\frac{1}{6}D^3P^{-1}+\cdots$$
$$P(I+D+\frac{1}{2}D^2+\frac{1}{6}D^3+\cdots)P^{-1}$$
$$=Pe^D P^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is a consequence of the fact that conjugation by an invertible matrix $A$ preserves products of matrices, i.e., that $A(XY)A^{-1} = (AXA^{-1})(AYA^{-1})$ for any matrices $X,Y$.

So you have $$e^{PDP^{-1}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {(PDP^{-1})^{k}}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {PD^{k}P^{-1}}{k!} = P \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {D^{k}}{k!}\right)P^{-1} = Pe^{D}P^{-1}$$